# Group by different column names in a df using in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, group-by

I'm new to R, recently I tried to use a for loop to put every different col names in a group by statement, then make a graph accordingly. However I got this error

Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.

*Column `i` is not found.

below is the code, I kinda simplify the problem here, only kept the group by part, does anyone know how I can solve this?

```
for (i in colnames(mtcars)) {
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(i) %>%
    summarise((total=n())
}
```

Comment: What is the `total=`

Comment: Write `group_by(.data[[i]])` instead of `group_by(i)`.

Comment: Apologize there's a typo here, it should be total=n(), but thank you @dash2 this is exactly what I need!